# Load External SWF, assign MOUSE_DOWN event, and prevent empty space / sub stage from being clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, loader, stage

I've been developing in Flash now for over 15 years, and recently started developing games in Flash Actionscript 3. I am having some difficulties, and need some help. I've spent days trying to find a solution, with no luck.

I have a main SWF, which loads sub SWF animations. One object can have 5 different animations / SWFs associated with it. So lets say I have a chicken, chicken01.swf, chicken02.swf, ...

I assign a MOUSE_DOWN event to the first loaded SWF, then based on the tool used while clicking on the object, it will load the other animations. My problem is that each SWF has empty space around it which becomes clickable. I only need the object clickable, and not the empty space, because some of the objects can overlap each other, which makes it hard to click on the object behind another object.

The Sub SWFs / animations are on a single timeline, and I played with Bitmap Tracing to remove the empty space around the imported PNG objects. This works if I reduce the Stage size to behind the Object, but then screws up the size of the loaded SWF due to the Stage size being smaller than the object. So when I assign a width and height to the object, with a smaller stage, the object is huge. If I constraint the stage size to the size of the object, even as a Traced bitmap image, the stage is still clickable. I tried to assign the MOUSE_DOWN event to the object on the sub SWF, from the Main SWF, but this gives errors.

**My goal is to load a sub SWF, assign the MOUSE_DOWN event, and only have the object clickable, and not the Stage, or empty space around the object.**

Is this possible? I also played around with creating an invisible button, but this makes it difficult to assign to 300 + objects of different shapes and sizes.

Below is some of the code I'm using.

```
var loadimage = foreground_list[i].imagelocation + foreground_list[i].image;

var loader:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader(loadimage,{container:tn_mc,x:current_tn_x,y:current_tn_y,name:current_name,alpha:1,width:current_tn_w,height:current_tn_h,rotation:0});

loader.load();
tn_mc.buttonMode = true;

tn_mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, tn_down );
tn_mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, tn_up );

addChild( tn_mc );


function tn_down(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch (MovieClip(this.root).PointerTool)
    {
        case "move" :

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_up );

            e.target.startDrag();
            break;
        case "play" :

            var loader4:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader(foreground_list.imagelocation + foreground_list.playimage,{container:tn_mc,name:e.target.name,x:foreground_list.setx,y:foreground_list.sety,width:foreground_list.setw,height:foreground_list.seth,rotation:0});
            tn_mc.removeChildAt(0);
            tn_mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, tn_down );
            tn_mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, tn_up );

            loader4.load();
            loader4.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeactionHandler);
            break;

        default :
            //Some other animation
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should target an instance inside your loaded SWF and not the whole SWF.

Answer (score 1):

Create a movieclip - a vector shape inside each swf, that is the same shape as your clickable area.  Set the alpha to 0% on the vector's fill color.  Give it and instance name of something like **activeArea**, and assign your event listener to that instead of the outer shell moveiclip.

Another approach that might work is to use **hitTestObject()** on a **MOUSE_DOWN** event, which would allow you to choose to ignore the transparency.

**EDIT**

Hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do without seeing it.  I didn't actually compile this so I'm not sure if this will work just the way it is, but in theory it should be close.  Its a slightly different approach than you are using.  I used Loader() instead of SWFLoader, and cleaned up the idea a little bit.  As a side note, you should avoid the use of **root** in as3.

```
var _swfLoader:Loader;

var loadimage = foreground_list[i].imagelocation + foreground_list[i].image;

var loader:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader(loadimage,{container:tn_mc,x:current_tn_x,y:current_tn_y,name:current_name,alpha:1,width:current_tn_w,height:current_tn_h,rotation:0});

loader.load();
tn_mc.buttonMode = true;

tn_mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, tn_down );

addChild( tn_mc );

function tn_down(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    tn_mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, tn_up );

    switch (MovieClip(this.root).PointerTool)
    {
        case "move" :

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_up );
            e.target.startDrag();

        break;

        case "play" :

            _swfLoader = new Loader();
            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(foreground_list.imagelocation + foreground_list.playimage);
            _swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, animationLoaded);

            _swfLoader.load(req);

        break;

        default :

            //Some other animation

        break;
    }
}

function tn_up(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    tn_mc.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, tn_up );
}

function animationLoaded(evt:Event):void
{
    _swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, animationLoaded);

    tn_mc.removeChildAt(0);

    var loadedSwf = evt.target.content;
    loadedSwf.x = foreground_list.setx;
    loadedSwf.y = foreground_list.sety;
    loadedSwf.width = foreground_list.setw;
    loadedSwf.height = foreground_list.seth;
    loadedSwf.rotation = 0;

    loadedSwf.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onAnimationStart);

    // might wanna add theses to an array to keep track of them and run clean up later on

    // now add to some display list
}

function onAnimationStart(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    loadedSwf.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onAnimationStop);

    // play your animation or whatever else
    evt.target.play();
}

function onAnimationStop(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    loadedSwf.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onAnimationStop);

    // stop your animation or whatever else
    evt.target.stop();
}
```

Comment: I'll try both and see which one works the best. Can you give an example of how to use the hitTestObject() function? Would this go in the MOUSE_DOWN function? I appreciate your quick response. So use to the old AS2 days and started working with AS3 last year. I like it, but things that were so easy in AS2, seem to take more time to build out in AS3.

Comment: I just did a quick test on hittest, not gonna work, stick with the first idea.  But to answer your question, there are two ways, hitTestPoint, which compares a point against an object:  myMovieClip.hitTestPoint(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY).  The other is hitTestObject, which compares if two objects are overlapping: myMovieClip.hitTestObject(MyOtherMovieClip).  They both have a optional third boolean parameter that denotes whether to include the bounding area of the movieclip including transparency, or to only pay attention to visible pixels.

Comment: Tried both ways and just not having success. Created the Vector outline with 0 alpha, but had to convert to symbol to apply instance name, unless there is another way of adding an instance name. I just can't figure out how to apply a click event from the main SWF. The hitTest always comes back as false no mater where I click. Used mouseX and mouseY, but does not help. Any ideas on the code for these functions. Did research on hitTest and tried a few examples with no luck.

Comment: Just to help out, I zipped up an example, and uploaded this to a site for you to check out. http://www.yourcrib.net/testchicken.zip This has the source fla files as well. I'm going to continue to test, just thought this would help. This does not include the vector outline. Let me know if you have any questions or find something.

Comment: I edited my answer with another approach.  take a look and I'll look at your code in the meantime.

Comment: crap.  cs5.  can you save as cs4?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, long day at work. I saved as CS4 and uploaded to the same link as above. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Just checking in to see if you found a solution to the click function?